# IIS published website is not accessible with public ip and port

Tags: iis, asp.net, port-forwarding, web, web-applications

I have IIS published web application that I can connect with my local ip and port. Like 192.168.1.99:81

After adding inbounding rules, router DMZ and port forwarding, closing both windows and router firewall, I can not access to web application with my public ip and port.

I am trying to reach it like https://publicIp:81

When I check to port it says, port is closed and when I try to reach it gives connection time put.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Hi Matt. I didn't have default config for 80, after installing IIS, should I check anything else in Windows firewall?

Comment: Eep.  It struck me as a stupid comment so I deleted.  What else... Have you looked at localhost:81 from the server itself?  (Not quite what you asked, just asking a basic question)

Comment: Yeah I did it, it works. I also checked with my phone on same lan.
I am binding with myIP:81 and hostname:81

Comment: Apologies, you kind of covered that already in your question.  Sorry.  You've managed to isolate the issue to the router, I think.  Someone might be able to chime in with if you give specifics about the router.  (?)

Comment: I actually figured out event I close router firewall, add my local IP to DMZ and add rule for port forwarding, port is not open. Do you think it would cause this?

Comment: I am having trouble with your last.  Autocorrect issue? Anyway, I'm thinking through this... You added PRIVATEIP to the DMZ and forwarded EXTERNALIP:81 to PRIVATEIP:81.  You can see LOCALHOST:81 from the server and you can see PRIVATEIP:81 from your local network.  I guess I'm wondering about your ISP now:  Is this a commercial connection or home?  And are there other things you've served up from this network in the past?

Comment: My Router's DMZ works with only IP therefore I don't have option to forward as you mean. It is home, I did connect before but it keeps saying time out now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104483/discussion-between-matt-murphy-and-meo).